# Guid partition key for Entity Framework Core Cosmos DB provider

Tags: entity-framework-core, azure-cosmosdb, ef-core-3.1

I'm trying to use the EF Core Cosmos DB provider and in my entity class I'm using a Guid as Id. Also, the Guid value will be the partition key in the Cosmos DB collection. The EF Core Cosmos DB provider documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/cosmos/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) says that the: "**The partition key property can be of any type as long as it is converted to string.**"
My entity class looks something like:

```
public class UserDto
{
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName ="id")]                
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public CountryDto Country { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
    }
}
```

In the DB context class I have something like:

```
public class CosmosDbContext : DbContext
{
    public CosmosDbContext(DbContextOptions<CosmosDbContext> options)  : base(options)
    {

    }

    public DbSet<UserDto> Users { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDto>()
            .ToContainer("Users");

        var converter = new GuidToStringConverter();
        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDto>()
            .Property("Id")
            .HasConversion(converter);

        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDto>()                
            .HasPartitionKey(x => x.Id);


        modelBuilder.Entity<UserDto>()
            .OwnsOne(u => u.Country);            
    }
}
```

Whenever I'm trying to add a new user to the collection I get the following error:
**Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos.CosmosException : Response status code does not indicate success: 400 Substatus: 1001 Reason: (Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException: Message: {"Errors":["PartitionKey extracted from document doesn't match the one specified in the header"]}**

If I don't have a partitioning key in my collection and I remove code that sets the partitioning key and the value converter in the OnModelCreating method the code will work just fine.

According to this link: https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/12086 the value converters should work.
What am I missing?

Thank you!

Comment: In case anyone is having similar issues...
I've just tried to use the `GuidToStringConverter` and it seemed to work. I'm using .net core 5 but apart from that the only difference I can see between yours and mine is that the entity has an **Id** field and a **PartitionKey** field. In my case the values are different but you can use the same values.